# Type object that has many "key: require()" entries, to make all requires as strings

Tags: typescript

I have object like this that has multiple keys and values (requires).

```
export const BACKGROUND_IMGS = {
  fire: require('$images/backgrounds/background_fire.jpg')
};
```

Typescript currently inherits its type as

```
const BACKGROUND_IMGS: {
    fire: any;
}
```

Is it possible to change that `any` into a `string`, without appending `as string` after every require, while also keeping correct key type (one typescript auto-inherits)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly define the types that will be the `BACKGROUND_IMGS` keys and define `BACKGROUND_IMGS` as a `Record` of those:

```
type YourElement = "fire" | "water";

export const BACKGROUND_IMGS: Record<YourElement, string> = {
  fire: require("..."),
  water: require("...")
};
```

To get around this duplication of keys, another way to do this is using `keyof` to create a new type with the objects key and declare a new type with that:

```
const BACKGROUND_IMGS = {
  fire: require(".."),
  water: require("..")
};

type ImageKeys = keyof typeof BACKGROUND_IMGS;
export const BACKGROUND_IMGS_TYPED = BACKGROUND_IMGS as Record<ImageKeys,string>;
```

Comment: If I do that, I loose reference to the `fire` entry, as it now becomes just a string. Ideally I'd like to keep those for auto completion.

Comment: @Ilja: I see, updated. But I think there might be a simpler way to do this, I'll check :)

Comment: Yeh, I'm trying to figure out a way to do this with "lowest effort" approach I guess. Solution above works, but requires certain degree of duplication

Comment: I think I found another way to do this using `keyof` without having to explicitly duplicate the object's keys. But let's keep this question open to see if the experts find an even better solution :)